# Socket communication response time varies by device

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, sockets

The project I am working on requires a NodeMCU (ESP8266 WiFi module) to connect to a gateway (Advantech ARK-1123) equipped with a wireless adapter. After having the gateway create a separate wireless network and connecting the Node, I found that the response time of receiving a message from the gateway as a socket client and sending back some data is **350ms** per line sent back.

After dissecting the NodeMCU code and finding nothing that could cause this, I tried testing the same program with different devices. The results were that it takes ~**350ms** to send one line to the gateway, ~**150ms** to another PC with a usb wireless adapter, and ~**10ms** to my phone with a TCP client app, regardless of the network used, or the way the PCs are connected to the network (wired or wireless).
I am sure (well, more like hope) there is some network setting I am overlooking on the PCs, which is default on the phone. The goal would be to have the time down to 10-15ms on the gateway.

Any ideas?

Comment: Different network cards, different MTU sizes, different operating systems and network stacks, different loads on the system.

Comment: Sure, but does it makes sense that my phone is faster to receive data than a PC? Also, 350ms seems absurd to send a string to a device on the same network.

Comment: A [NodeMCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NodeMCU) runs multiple abstraction layers of interpreted languages, has single RISC core with ~80 MHz and ~128 kB memory. Depending on what you do I image it's rather easy to bottleneck it. In addition your numbers only talk about wireless performance which might be anything from a to ac+ depending on what you actually do and how you connect the device(s). As it is you have any number of variables that might influence the response times.

Comment: I stripped my NodeMCU code from anything unrelated to this communication to make sure its not dependent on its performance. I can attach the code or provide any configuration, if you think that would help.
I feel like a communication as basic as socket com is should not take this long time. Pinging the device responds in 4-5ms, which seems way more likely.

Comment: So these tests were over TCP? Was TLS involved? Was the TCP session up already or were you having to do a 3-way handshake each time? Was your listener already running or was it getting lazy-launched by xinetd (or systemd or whatever)?